# 301 Redirect with ColdFusion dynamic url

Tags: url, redirect, iis

Long time listeners, first time callers.

We are trying to accept old inbound links, that are currently bouncing.

The old urls contain: /County_Detail.cfm/CountyID:XXX   *(XXX = UniqueID)*

We want the old links to redirect to /Counties/County_Detail.cfm?CountyID=XXX

We're using CF10 and IIS 8.5

We simply want to replace the delimiters / and :

We've tried a number of settings, with the following as the latest:

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Rewrite Counties" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="^County_Detail.cfm([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)CountyID([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)" />
<action type="Redirect" url="County_Detail.cfm{R:1}CountyID{R:2}" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Would someone kindly point out the error of our ways.

Thank you, so much!

Comment: What do you mean replace the delimiters / and : ? If you want to redirect old url to new one,  `match url` should be `^County_Detail.cfm/([a-zA-Z0-9-+]+)`, Action url should be `/Counties/County_Detail.cfm?CountyID={R:0}`